# Count the occurrence of specific words on a text file and print the 50 most occurred ones among them

Tags: python

I want to count the occurrence of specific keywords (stored in .txt file, one word each line) in a text file.And print the 50 most occurred ones. Here's what I did :

```
from collections import Counter

with open("./Text_file.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as logfile:
    word_counts = Counter(logfile.read().split())

with open("./key_words.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as word:
    lines = word.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        count = [word_counts.get('line')]
lst = sorted (count)
print (lst[:50])
```

I returns this to me, which doesn't mean anything :

```
[20]
```

Any help ?

Comment: Note that the entire second block only queries, over and over again, the word count for *the word* ``"line"``.

Comment: Do: `count.append(word_counts.get('line'))` and initialize `count` as empty list at the beginning of your loop.

Comment: @Asocia This will also just repeatedly look for the count of ``'line'``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Well, I just copy pasted from OP and didn't realize the quotes around `'line'`. Yes, that's right, it should be `line` not `'line'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Option

```
from collections import Counter

# Read keywords
with open("./key_words.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as keyfile:
  # Use set of keywords (@MisterMiyagi comment)
  keywords = set(keyfile.read().split('\n'))

# Process words
with open("./Text_file.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as logfile:
  cnts = Counter()
  for line in logfile:
    if line:
      line = line.rstrip()
      # only count keywords
      cnts.update(word for word in line.split() if word in keywords)

# Use counter most_common to get most popular 50
print(cnts.most_common(50))
```

**Alternative Using Counter+Regex**

Regex used to separate words from punctuation i.e. perids, quotes, commas, etc.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open("./key_words.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as keyfile:
  keywords = keyfile.read().lower().split('\n')

with open("./Text_file.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as logfile:
  cnts = Counter()
  for line in logfile:
    # use regex to separate words from punctuation
    # lowercase words
    words = map(lambda x:x.lower(), re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', line, flags=re.A))
    cnts.update(word for word in words if word in keywords)

print(cnts.most_common(50))
```

Comment: Note that using a ``set`` for the ``keywords`` instead of the implicit ``list`` scales better for large numbers of keywords.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi--ah, details, I keep forgetting the details--you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

```
from collections import Counter

with open("./Text_file.txt", "r") as file,open("./key_words.txt", "r") as word:
    words1 = [w.strip() for w in file.read().split()] # Strore words from text file into list
    words2 = [w.strip() for w in word.read().split()] # Strore words from key file into list

s = [w1 for w1 in words1 if w1 in words2] # List all words from text file that are in key file

d = Counter(s) # Diction that stores each word from s with the amount of times the word occurs in s

lst = [w for k,w in sorted([(v,k) for k,v in d.items()],reverse=True)[:50]]

print(lst)
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at ``collections.Counter``, as used in the question as well. A ``set`` is likely more appropriate than a ``list`` for ``words2``, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

On here `word_counts.get('line')`, you are calling for just the occurances of `line` on every iteration, which is why your result list has single value. Following is modified code of yours for top 50 words from keywords.

```
from collections import Counter

with open("./Text_file.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as logfile:
    word_counts = Counter(logfile.read().split())

wc = dict(word_counts)
kwc = {}    #keyword counter
with open("./key_words.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as word:
    lines = word.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip() #assuming each word is in separate line, removes '\n' character from end of line
        if line in wc.keys():
            kwc.update({line:wc[line]}) # if keyword is found, adds that to kwc

lst = sorted (kwc, key = kwc.get, reverse = True)   #sorts in decreasing order on value of dict
print (lst[:50])
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code - you were close but needed to fix a few things:

- You were only storing a single `count`, not building a list of words. I solved this by making a new dict of words-to-counts, but only for the found keywords.
- As others have said, you were using the string literal `'line'` instead of `line`
- You weren't stripping the newline from each `line` - when you use `readlines()` the `\n` newline is at the end of each line, so none of your words were being found in your `Counter`.

So, here's the code. It prints out the keywords in descending order of counts, and just the 1st 50:

```
from collections import Counter
with open("./Text_file.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as logfile:
    word_counts = Counter(logfile.read().split())

found_keywords = {}
with open("./key_words.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as word:
    lines = word.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.rstrip()
        count = word_counts[line]
        if count > 0:
            found_keywords[line] = count

>>> print([(k, v) for k, v in sorted(found_keywords.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)][:50])
[('cat', 3), ('dog', 1)]
```